# High GC load using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, garbage-collection

I have developed a web application using Spring MVC + Hibernate and when running load tests it seems the Garbage Collector is being called too often. I am afraid it might have to do with the way I manage Hibernates session.

I have an AbstractDao which all of my DAO objects extends:

```
public class AbstractDaoHibernateImpl {

    protected GenericDataBaseExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    public AbstractDaoHibernateImpl() {
    }

    public void setExceptionHandler(GenericDataBaseExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

In spring entity bean configuration I define each of my DAOs like this:

```
   <bean name="userDao" class="com.kelmer.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
        <property name="exceptionHandler" ref="defaultSpringExceptionHandler" />
    </bean>
```

And then this is a sample method from one of my DAOs:

```
    @Override
    public EstacionVO findById(Long id) throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        User e = (User ) getSession().createQuery(SELECT_USER_BY_ID).setParameter("userId", id).uniqueResult();
        if (e == null) {
            throw new InstanceNotFoundException ("No user with provided Id", User.class);
        }
        return e;
    }
```

I honestly can see anything that might be causing a memory leak but then again I'm no real expert here. Am I doing session management right? I know I took the code from AbstractDao from some legacy code and I fear that's where the memory problem could be, since there is no explicit session closing or finalizing.

PS. For transaction management, I am using `<tx:annotation-driven />` in spring context and annotating each method with `@Transactional`.

Comment: I would use `Session.load(class, PrimaryKey)` to load an object by its Primary Key, instead of using a query.

Comment: It was just a sample query, not a real case scenario

Comment: Maybe you should post the real code when asking a question about.

Comment: Maybe I just wanted to illustrate the way I execute queries, and not the query itself. The problem lives throughout the application so my guess is that it's not related to any specific query.

Comment: If you are using Spring and you have proper tx management setup the session should be closed after the transaction finished. If you don't have proper tx or a wrong tx integration for spring you might be leaking sessions. However without your actual tx configuration and/or spring setup this is hard to determine.

Comment: True. I edited my original post. I use annotations and annotate with @Transactional each method.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, there doesn't seem to be anything unusual in your code.

Run a performance monitor to see what objects are created.

Unless the problem is trivial, it's hard to see where performance is lost by just looking at the code and 90% of the time, any statement "it must be this" turns out to be wrong.

Comment: Can you recommend a good performance monitor? I would like to run tests that stress my app

Answer (score 1):

What is your hibernate session creation strategy. Is your code using the same session again and again? 
Instead of :

```
protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

try opening a new session for each request:

```
protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Each session has a session cache to which all retrieved or persisted objects are added. If you keep on using the same session for querying many-many entities, it 'may' lead to such a scenario.

Give the change a try and do let us know if helps.

**The right way**

Use one of the performance monitoring tools to see what's really causing the issue: 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-performance-troubleshooti-0

Comment: In a Spring world you should never use `openSession` as that leads to hibernate sessions not managed by spring which will lead you to all sorts of problems.